# How can I get a CREATE ROLE query of existing role in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to do something like this:

`SHOW CREATE ROLE my_role_name;`

I couldn't find it in export query options either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the DBMS_METADATA package:

```
set long 20000 longchunksize 20000 pagesize 0 linesize 1000 feedback off verify off trimspool on
column ddl format a1000

begin
   dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
   dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
end;
/

variable v_role VARCHAR2(30);

exec :v_role := upper('&1');

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('ROLE', r.role) AS ddl
from   dba_roles r
where  r.role = :v_role
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('ROLE_GRANT', rp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_role_privs rp
where  rp.grantee = :v_role
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('SYSTEM_GRANT', sp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_sys_privs sp
where  sp.grantee = :v_role
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT', tp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_tab_privs tp
where  tp.grantee = :v_role
and    rownum = 1
/
```

Source: https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=script_creation&file=role_ddl.sql